# Audio file not play in some phones

Tags: java, android, audio-player

I'm trying to playing a recorded file on the phone. It works in Lenovo 4.2 and Oppo 5.0 but it gives the error "couldn't play the track" in Moto E 5.0 and Samsung SM-N915G 6.0

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/PhoneCallRecording/" + callNumber.get(position).getDate() + ".amr");
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: maybe there is no app installed that can catch the intent. Check with `if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)` before starting the activity. That checks if an app is available for that intent.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs at time of file save if i changed extension i.e .amr to .mp3 not played in lenovo.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs.. Not Working..